# Number of ways to mark the edges of a net of regular tetrahedra

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, 3d, combinatorial-geometry

**Abstract**

This problem originates from Chemistry. You will soon find that the Oxygen and Hydrogen in the image can be replaced with vertices and arrows, which is why I propose it here. Although its main purpose is to practice Chemistry, the Mathematics part of it is absolutely not trivial.

**Problem**

Given a net of tetrahedra and their centers. The edges of the tetrahedra themselves are not matched, but the lines connecting the vertices and the centers of the tetrahedra. To illustrate, let's have a look at the example given in the book:

[image: Don't look at the black and white atoms1]

Ignoring the black points, mark each edge with an arrow so that, for each vertex, there are 2 arrows coming from and 2 arrows coming to it. Define a *box* the outer boundary of the net, so any edge that is not inside or lies on the surface of the *box* is not counted. How many ways are there to mark the edges  of a $n \times n \times n$ *box* with arrows? (The illustration above is a $3 \times 3 \times 2$ box)

I attempted to convert the problem to a directed Graph on the plane, with the degree of each edge equal to 4, and each pair of edge from a vertex is also a pair of exactly one hexagon. But I feel that the conditions are not tight enough to solve this problem.

Any idea would be appreciated.

**Edit**: I have indeed found an estimated answer to the question [here](https://www.princeton.edu/%7Efhs/fhspapers/fhspaper20.pdf) (please scroll to page 2 to read the mathematical solution), still I need a better explanation to the problem so that we can calculate the exact value of the answer.

Comment: This looks fun. Which book is it ? What does it say about that problem ?

Comment: It's merely curiosity, but as you say the problem comes from chemistry, how is counting the ways to draw these arrows related to chemistry?

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut the arrow pointing out is actually hydrogen attached to the oxygen while arrow pointing to is hydrogen connecting Oxygens with oxygens, (as you might notice in the image). In the original problem, they asked for the number of possible ways to form a net of oxygen and hydrogen in an ice cube so that we can calculate the stability of the compound (I think so, I'm not a specialist in Chemistry, this question is just from a friend preparing for IChO), as

Comment: Thanks. Olympiads, that makes sense.

Comment: For large values of $n$ one could try asymptotic solutions. Ignoring the boundary of the box we can say the following. If there are $k$ vertices, there are $2k$ edges. At each vertex 6 out of 16 possible arrow assignments satisfy the 2 in 2 out condition. Hence if we assume the conditions at different vertices are independent (I don't think they are) we get $2^{(2k)}*(6/16)^k=(3/2)^k$ possibilities as a first approximation.

Comment: @quarague that was what I mentioned in the edit. But is there a more specific answer?

Comment: For me, the link in your edit is dead. I just get a princeton page not found error.

Comment: Though I think your answer is quite similar, it might be helpful to you if I repost the link here. I just clicked and it still shows the report: https://www.princeton.edu/~fhs/fhspapers/fhspaper20.pdf